# Copy same worksheet in different Excel to one destination Excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple Excel files and they all have the same Worksheet in them named Fixture.

I am trying to copy all of them (they are all in the same folder) and paste them in my destination Excel file under the name of the original Excel file.

For example:

`[Excel1]Fixture` will be a new worksheet in Main.xlsx named Excel1 after running the VBA. Same with Excel2, Excel3, etc.

Please help!

Comment: Do you have the routine to go through all the files and open them? Are you able to add sheets to Main.xlsx? Copy the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you act in four steps:

1. Create a workbook, e.g. "Collect.xlsx" to collect all "Fixture" sheets
2. Get your Excel file names and loop through them
3. In the loop, copy each "Fixture" sheet to your Collect.xlsx
4. Close and save Collect.xlsx

To 2: You can get the Excel file names either by `dir()` or by `fileDialog`:

- `dir`:
  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
  You can use it with or without parameter, thus looping through a
  directory. Useful if you want a simple loop, or if you have hundreds of files.
- `FileDialog`: Use the famous FileDialog by Karsten Pries. You can select multiple names 
  and then loop through them. Download: http://www.kpries.de/download/FileDialog.zip

Your loop might look somehow like this:

```
...
...
fileDialog.Filter1Suffix = "*.xls"
fileDialog.Filter1Text = "Excel Dokumente"
fileDialog.ShowOpen
fileName = fileDialog.fileName
Do While fileName <> ""
   ImportOneSheet fileName ' <<< your own method to collect Fixture
   fileName = fileDialog.GetNextFile
Loop
...
```

If you use `dir`, just set your `ImportOneSheet` method in the `dir` loop.

To 3: Some crucial commands are:

- `Application.Workbooks.Open (fileName)`
- `Set myExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")`
- `Set importWorkBook = Application.ActiveWorkbook`
- `importWorkBook.Sheets("Fixture").range("A:ZZ").Copy`
- `collectorWorkBook.Sheets(consolidationSheetName).range("A:ZZ").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, True, False`
- `importWorkBook.Close`

These are merely *snippets* to give you ideas. You might want to find out more about these.

To 4: use the saveAs command: `xlam.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs path, xlOpenXMLWorkbook, , , False, False` and the close command: `xlam.Workbooks.Close`.

For anything remaining, you will find tons of snippets in the net. Good luck :-)